# How to re-render the same component being used in different routes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have several routes rendering the same component. Depending on the route I want the component to fetch different data. However since I keep rendering the same component, React doesn't see any changes to the DOM when I click a Link tag (from my nav bar located in the Layout component) to another route rendering that same component. Meaning the component is not re-rendered with the new data. Here are my routes:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Layout>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/fashion" component={PostTypePageContainer} />
              <Route exact path="/beauty" component={PostTypePageContainer} />
            </Switch>
          </Layout>
        </Provider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Here is the PostTypePageContainer component that I want to re-render with the new data each time:

```
class PostTypePageContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let route;
    switch (this.props.location.pathname) {
      case '/fashion':
        route = '/fashion';
        break;
      case '/beauty':
        route = '/beauty';
        break;
      default:
        console.log('No data was found');
    }

    let dataURL = `http://localhost:8888/my-site//wp-json/wp/v2${route}?_embed`;
    fetch(dataURL)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.props.dispatch(getData(res));
      });
  }

  render() {
    let posts = this.props.postData.map((post, i) => {
      return <PostTypePage key={i} props={post} />;
    });
    return <div>{posts}</div>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ data }) => ({
  postData: data.postData
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PostTypePageContainer);
```

How do I go about re-rendering that component each time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is intended behavior of react-router.

While i suggest you create a HOC to fetch the data from different locations and pass it to the `PostTypePageContainer` via props, using a key will give you a quick work around that will cause your component to remount.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Layout>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact key={uniqueKey} path="/fashion" component={PostTypePageContainer} />
              <Route exact key={someOtherUniqueKey} path="/beauty" component={PostTypePageContainer} />
            </Switch>
          </Layout>
        </Provider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Source: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1703

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the <Route key={...} ... /> to work in my case. After trying several different approaches the one that worked for me was using the componentWillReceiveProps function in the reused component. This was getting called each time the component was called from a <Route />

In my code, I did:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextContext) {

    // When we receive a call with a new tag, update the current
    // tag and refresh the content
    this.tag = nextProps.match.params.tag;
    this.getPostsByTag(this.tag);
}
```

Comment: Update from 2019. ComponentWillReceiveProps is sort of an anti-pattern in React and is being deprecated https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops... It seems from the example above that you could pass the props.match.params.tag value as the key to the Route components. Make sure the tag values are actually unique.